# Sprite transparency not effected libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I am making a game using libGDX and Tween Universal Engine.
My problem is as follows:
I have 2 screens so fars, a splash screen with the logo, and a second one which is the main menu.
In the splash screen I use a `SpriteBatch` and a `Sprite` with the `Texture` of the image I want (which goes through some scaling.)
Now I use the Tween engine, along with a created `SpriteAccessor` to control the alpha of the sprite. I fade the picture in, then fade it out, then change it to the next screen.
In the next screen I have a single sprite, and a single, 3 slot, sprite array. In this screen I also use the tween engine, I fade the single sprite into the screen (it's the background image) then I try to, using the same method, (`Tween.to`) to change the alpah of the sprite array (each sprite by itself.),  I first set it to 0 using `Tween.set`, then using the method I change it.
This didn't work, after some tests I tried setting the alpha of a single sprite from the array to 0, and that didn't work.
It's like the program is ignoring the alpha value, I even printed out the alpha value, it saying 0, but the sprite is visible.
How can I fix this, or why might it be caused?

Comment: `SpriteBatch.enableBlending()` and `SpriteBatch.setBlendFunction()`

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem

This is my solution

```
public class SpriteAccessor implements TweenAccessor<Sprite> {

    public static final int ALPHA = 1;

    @Override
    public int getValues(Sprite sprite, int tweenType, float[] returnValues) {
        switch (tweenType) {
            case ALPHA: {
                returnValues[0] = sprite.getColor().a;
                return 1;
            }
            default: {
                assert false;
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setValues(Sprite sprite, int tweenType, float[] newValues) {
        switch (tweenType) {
            case ALPHA: {
                sprite.setAlpha(newValues[0]);
                break;
            }
            default: {
                assert false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

GameScreen class setup tweening after registering accessor and instantiate TweenManager

```
Tween.set(Art.nextButton, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA).target(0.5f).start(mTweenManager);
Tween.to(Art.nextButton, SpriteAccessor.ALPHA, 1.0f)
            .target(1.0f)
            .repeatYoyo(10, 0.2f)
            .start(mTweenManager);
```

GameScreen class render loop

```
mTweenManager.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
spriteBatch.begin();
Art.nextButton.draw(spriteBatch);
spriteBatch.end();
```